# Populate model with default attributes

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am building a website using the Spring-MVC framework. In the template I want to include some 'generic' information. Generic in the way that this is not specific to the current controller, but used on every page. This can be something like a generated menu, the number of minutes a user is logged in or the current temperature on the north pole.

**What I am currently doing**
I've made an abstract class with a method to populate the model with the default values. My controllers extend this class and I call this method in every (@RequestMapping-ed) method, which is a downside. It feels kinda hacky and is not very flexible.

```
@Component
public abstract class AbstractBaseController {
    @Autowired private SomeService someService;

    protected void populateModel(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("value", someService.getGenericValue());
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
public class HomeController extends AbstractBaseController {
    @RequestMapping("/") public String index(Model model) {
        populateModel(model);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**My question**
How should I provide these generic attributes to my view. Is there a better way than what I am doing now?

*(I am using Spring/Spring-MVC 4, JavaConfig, Thymeleaf with thymeleaf-layout-dialect)*

Comment: What is your template engine? What technique are you using for rendering pages? The best way from my point of view is to define a separate controller method for delivering of this information and "bind" this method with @RequestMapping to the specific page area. You can then request your "generic" attributes by JavaScript request from the page and deliver this data as e.g JSON.

Comment: As mentioned at the bottom of the post I am using Thymeleaf. If I understand correctly your suggestion would mean additional http-requests to fetch the data. Are you sure this is desirable?

Comment: Yes, in this case no of your controller needs to know about this attributes. They are absolutely transparent for the business logic. It's just one specific method related to the delivering of "generic" attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I actually wasn't that hard. You can annotate a method with `@ModelAttribute` which makes it available in the template.

```
@Component
public abstract class AbstractBaseController {
    @Autowired private SomeService someService;

    @ModelAttribute("value")
    protected String getValue() {
        return someService.getGenericValue());
    }
}
```

Mind you, this method will always be called. Also when `${value}` is not called in the template. So it is not more 'flexible' than the method I described in the question.